# How to configure a parse-server app to run Cloud Code on back4app

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-cloud-code, parse-server, back4app

A brief and clear explanation of how we configure the **app.js** file and whether we need to require **parse-server** in it is needed basically. Which files should and shouldn't be related with each other?

For example this is the **main.js** file where a simple **Cloud Code** function is defined:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(request, response){
    response.success('Hello world.');
}, function(error){
    response.error(error);
});
```

So how should the **app.js** file be configured in order to run that **Cloud Code** function?

```
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routers/index');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', index);
app.listen();
```

The above code example of an **app.js** file doesn't require and has no configuration of **parse-server**, does it need to?

```
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();
route.get('/', function(req, res){
    Parse.Cloud.run('hello').then(function(r){
        res.send(r);
    }, function(error){
        res.status(400).send(error);
    });
});
module.exports = route;
```

The above code example of a call in **routers/index.js** file to a **Cloud Code** function doesn't work. Is it because the file should require the **main.js** file or not?

Simple examples of **app.js** and **routers/index.js** files will suffice and be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Back4App wrote in their Docs that they already configured some lines for us, they're:

‘express’ and ‘app’

//var app = express();

You can take a look at [this guide](https://docs.back4app.com/docs/integrations/webhosting-back4app/) too ;)

For you to know, it is not necessary to call the app.js file in main.js, the app.js is already configured on the Back4App side, but you can edit the routes, for example, in my app, I use a login via Express :)